# why i get null parameter value?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, parameters

I have problem with parameter at my web application. At some page (index.xhtml) i have:

```
...
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="backurl"/>
</f:metadata>

<h:form>
   <h:outputLabel value="backurl: #{backurl}"/>
   <h:commandButton image="/resources/graphics/poland.gif" action="#{userController.setLanguage('pl', param['backurl'])}"/>
</h:form>
```

`setLanguage()` method in `userController` managed bean:

```
public void setLanguage(String language, String backurl) {
    setLang(new Locale(language));

    ...
}
```

---

when i run application and go to index.xhtml page i see `backurl: /pages/login.xhtml`
but at `setLanguage` method second parametr (`backurl`) is null when i click and debug application

Where is problem ?

Comment: Use `#{userController.setLanguage('pl', backurl)}"`, it is simpler and you can keep your method definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you use this?

```
<h:commandButton action="#{userController.setLanguage}">
    <f:param name="param1" value="value1" />
    <f:param name="backurl" value="#{backurl}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

and then in your method

```
    public String setLanguage() {

      Map<String,String> params = 
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
      String param1= params.get("param1");
      String backurl= params.get("backurl");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#{userController.setLanguage('pl', backurl)}
```

this should work. (didn't test it)

there are many ways to pass parameters to a backing bean. [Here is a useful article](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the view-param value in the managed-bean (provide accessors for the introduced `backurl` member, also).

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="backurl" value="#{userController.backurl}" />
</f:metadata>
```

And then you can get rid of the second method parameter and get the `backurl` value from the variable in the managed-bean.

```
action="#{userController.setLanguage('pl')}"/>
```

The managed bean should look like this:

```
public class UserController {

    private String backurl;

    public String getBackurl() { return backurl; }

    public void setBackurl(String backurl) { this.backurl = backurl; }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        setLocale(new Locale(language));
        System.out.println(backurl); //this refers the variable in the managed-bean
    }

}
```